# Adding horizontal scrollbar to Ionic2's ion-slides

Tags: angular, ionic2, swiper.js

I am using Ionic2's [`ion-slides`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/) which works fine for me.

```
    <ion-slides [options]="extraOptions">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
            <img src="{{slide.image}}" />
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

I would like to add a horizontal scroll bar as shown here in the Swiper API http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.V6Lcx8twbqA (13th example) as the docs mention Swiper is what is used for `ion-slides`. The [source code for that example](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/13-scrollbar.html) has  `<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>` after the `<div class="swiper-wrapper">` tag.

The problem is that Ionic generates the HTML so how could I add the scrollbar feature on.

To add pagination bullets to slider, I only have to add `pager` attribute directive in the `ion-slides` tag. Is there something similar for the horizental scrollbar bar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't be done via Ionic's ion-slide component. See reply from one of the authors here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-slides/59450/3?u=brightpixels

```
Not at the moment. We've tried to keep the Slides API much simpler than the original Swiper API. But we plan on revisiting this post 2.0 final
```

I have resolved this by using swiper library directly and creating my own component.

- Install module via npm: `npm install swiper`
- At the top of the component file `declare var require`
- Then `var swiper = require('swiper')`

Comment: Hi sir do you have a sample code to implement a swiper for scroll-x?